# Тип структуры как параметер

Tags: golang

Можно ли в go передавать тип структуры как параметр функции/метода ? Например:

```
type MyEntity struct {}
type MyEntity2 struct {}
func goProc(t type) {
    b := make(t)
}

func TestEncription(test *testing.T) {
    goProc(MyEntity.type)
    goProc(MyEntity2.type)
}
```

Пиишу байндинг из дб. Если одна запись то ок:

```
type DbEntity interface {
bindEntity(rows *pgx.Rows, descriptionSlice []pgx.FieldDescription, colsCount *int)
```

}

```
func (customerEntity *CustomerEntity) bindEntity(rows *pgx.Rows, descriptionSlice []pgx.FieldDescription, colsCount *int) {
val, _ := rows.Values()
for i := 0; i < *colsCount; i++ {
    switch descriptionSlice[i].Name {
    case "customer_id":
        customerEntity.CustomerId = val[i].(int64)
    case "account_name":
        customerEntity.AccountName = val[i].(string)
    case "customer_name":
        customerEntity.CustomerName = val[i].(string)
    }
}
```

}

А вот если лист(слайс) обьэктов то проблема

```
func queryForList(rows *pgx.Rows) []interface{} {
defer rows.Close()
descriptionSlice := rows.FieldDescriptions()
colsCount := len(descriptionSlice)

var entitySlice []interface{}

for rows.Next() {
    //entity := CustomerEntity{} 
    //entitySlice = append(entitySlice, bindEntityFunc(rows, descriptionSlice, &colsCount))
}
return entitySlice
```

}

queryForList - для всех типов энтити. И он не чего незнает о типах

Comment: А зачем? Скорее всего, можно преобразовать эту конструкцию в интерфейс и его реализации.

Comment: Интерфейс решает проблему если одна запись. Хочу написать байндинг из дб.

Comment: На данный момент вижу решение такое, создать функциию : NewCustomer, NewAccount и т.д. и передавать в queryForList. Без дженериков кривинько, но работать будет.

Answer (score 1):

Вот, придумал без reflect.
Но со type switch внутри, так намного лучше если у тебя все типы известны на этапе компиляции.

https://play.golang.org/p/enekbRdLM4

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type CustomerEntity struct {
    Name string
    Meta struct {
        Desc string
        Properties map[string]string
        Users []string
    }
}

func NewCustomerEntity() *CustomerEntity {
    return &CustomerEntity{ Name: "hello" }
}

func queryForList(t interface{}) []interface{} {
    var entitySlice []interface{}
    var entity interface{}
    for i:=0; i< 1; i++ {
        switch t.(type) {
            case *CustomerEntity:
                entity = NewCustomerEntity()
            default:
        }
        entitySlice = append(entitySlice, entity)   
    }

    return entitySlice
}


func main() {   
    lst := queryForList((*CustomerEntity)(nil))
    fmt.Printf("%#v", lst[0])   
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, отличное решение !

Answer (score 0):

Придется использовать reflect, а он медленный.
И ты еще намучаешься с ним =)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type CustomerEntity struct {
    Name string
    Meta struct {
        Desc string
        Properties map[string]string
        Users []string
    }
}

func queryForList(t reflect.Type) []interface{} {
    var entitySlice []interface{}
    for i:=0; i< 1; i++ {
        entity := reflect.New(t.Elem())

        initializeStruct(t.Elem(), entity.Elem())
        f := entity.Elem().FieldByName("Name")
        f.Set(reflect.ValueOf("hello"))

        entitySlice = append(entitySlice, entity.Interface())   
    }

    return entitySlice 
}

func initializeStruct(t reflect.Type, v reflect.Value) {
  for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    f := v.Field(i)
    ft := t.Field(i)
    switch ft.Type.Kind() {
    case reflect.Map:
      f.Set(reflect.MakeMap(ft.Type))
    case reflect.Slice:
      f.Set(reflect.MakeSlice(ft.Type, 0, 0))
    case reflect.Chan:
      f.Set(reflect.MakeChan(ft.Type, 0))
    case reflect.Struct:
      initializeStruct(ft.Type, f)
    case reflect.Ptr:
      fv := reflect.New(ft.Type.Elem())
      initializeStruct(ft.Type.Elem(), fv.Elem())
      f.Set(fv)
    default:
    }
  }
}

func main() {   
    // Рекомендуется передавать именно пустой указатель, что бы не занимать память
    lst := queryForList(reflect.TypeOf((*CustomerEntity)(nil)))

    entity := lst[0].(*CustomerEntity)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", entity)

    // либо, если не знаешь к какому типу приводить
    val := reflect.ValueOf(lst[0])
    fmt.Println(val.Elem().FieldByName("Name"))
}
```

Через reflect в структуре можно заполнить только экспортируемые поля.

Можешь попробывать переписать на `lst := queryForList((*CustomerEntity)(nil))` с параметром interface{}, но у меня что-то быстро не получилось и я забил =)

Мучайся на здоровье